# How can I recompile a program so that it does not require setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH in order to run?

Tags: libraries, compile

On a solaris server where I don't have admin, I am compiling various software and installing in `$HOME/usr`, and it's mostly working. However, some of the programs that I compile in this way depend on libiconv, which I have also installed in `$HOME/usr/lib`. These programs will not run unless I `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/usr/lib`. If I do not do this, I get an error such as the following:

```
ld.so.1: rsync: fatal: libiconv.so.2: open failed: No such file or directory
```

This is expecially bad for rsync, because it does not always operate in a shell environment, so I don't even have the option of using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make it work. Is it possible to compile my programs such that I do not have to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for them to run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look up `rpath`.  With gcc, you pass `-Wl,-rpath,/directory/with/library` to the compile/link.  I think with the Solaris compiler the flag was `-R/directory/with/library`, but I have no Solaris machine to check with.

Comment: I'm using GCC on solaris, and I can use GNU binutils as well. So should I use the `-Wl` form?

Comment: Yeah, -Wl to pass to the linker, and -rpath is what binutils understands, or -Wl,-R,/directory/with/library should work as well (with solaris linker)

Comment: Can I put `-rpath /directory/with/library` in my LDFLAGS, or is it better to put `-Wl,-rpath,/directory/with/library` in my CFLAGS?

Comment: Probably -Wl,-rpath,/path/to/dir in LDFLAGS. Makefiles rarely use ld directly but use ${CC} to drive the ld line, so -Wl is appropriate.

Comment: Wait, don't you mean in CFLAGS?

Comment: To be honest I'd check in either way.
You can test your executable possibly.  On Linux I use `readelf -d` to see the section for RPATH, this may be doable with gnu binutils on Solaris.
BUT I meant `LDFLAGS`.  Think of `gcc` not as a compiler, but as a build tool driver.  One of the things it does is drive the link stage.  The link will (probably) be `gcc -o executable $OBJS $LDFLAGS $LIBS`. So, gcc wil pass (because of -Wl) to ld.

Comment: When I add this to my CFLAGS, I get `ld: fatal: option -dn and -P are incompatible` during `./configure`, after which it says the the C compiler can't create executables. GNU ld doesn't even have a -P option, so I'm pretty sure GCC is using the Solaris linker, even though I have GNU ld installed in a higher-priority path.

Comment: I tried with -R instead of -rpath, and it seems to work. I would still like to know how to use my own ld, but I guess that's another question.